# How to use a data attribute from a target div as view param in a PrimeFaces ContextMenu outcome

Tags: javascript, jquery, primefaces, jsf-2.2

I'm trying to do the following:

- From a simple collection of  elements...
- Add a PrimeFaces ContextMenu...
- Have the first menu option forward to a new page...
- Pass a data attribute from the selected  element as a view
  param.

It all seems pretty straightforward, until I come to the last step, and I can't seem to find a way to get this to work.

e.g.

```
  <div class="group" data-group="GRP1">
    ...
  </div>

  <div class="group" data-group="GRP2">
    ...
  </div>

  <div class="group" data-group="GRP3">
    ...
  </div>

  <p:contextMenu targetFilter="div.group">
    <p:menuitem value="Edit" outcome="group.xhtml?group=GRP???"/>
  </p:contextMenu>
```

The divs are generated HTML and I don't really have much control over those, so probably need to do something with Javascript on the client side.

I've tried to get hold of the group from the Javascript side, but I can't see how to bind a function to the beforeShow handler. I can see that if I can register the correct event handler then the PF code will pass me the event (from which I can get the target element and the data attribute):

```
  // from PF menu.js
  if(this.cfg.beforeShow) {
      var retVal = this.cfg.beforeShow.call(this, e);
      if(retVal === false) {
        return;
      }
  }
```

But I'm not sure how to access this - if I just use inline event registration then I can only pass Javascript code not a reference to my function:

```
  function doBeforeShow(menu, event) {
    var group = event.target.dataset['group'];
  }

  <p:contextMenu targetFilter="div.group" beforeShow="/* this is just executed JS not a bound function */">
```

Anyway, even if I could get the group from the JS side, I'm not really sure what I'd do with it... probably store it somewhere and attach another handler to the p:menuitem so when it was selected it could modify the outcome before calling it?

So I'm stuck! Anyone have any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this working, though not sure it is the best way...

Required a patch to PrimeFaces to store the jQuery event on the menu widget:

```
--- src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/menu/menu.js       (revision 12491)
+++ src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/primefaces/menu/menu.js       (working copy)
@@ -1109,6 +1109,9 @@
             top = top - height;
         }

+        // save the event which activated this menu
+        this.jqEvent = e;
+        
         if(this.cfg.beforeShow) {
             var retVal = this.cfg.beforeShow.call(this, e);
             if(retVal === false) {
```

Then added "widgetVar" to the contextMenu to name the menu widget and some client-side javascript to update the link before it is activated:

```
  <p:contextMenu targetFilter="div.group" widgetVar="ctxMenu">
    <p:menuitem value="Edit" onclick="fixGroupLink(PF('ctxMenu'), this);"
        outcome="group.xhtml?group=GRP???"/>
  </p:contextMenu>

  function fixGroupLink(menu, menuitem) {
    var grp = menu.jqEvent.target.dataset.group;
    menuitem.href = menuitem.href.replace(/group=.*$/, "group=" + grp);
  }
```

So this works, and I'll mark it as accepted for now, but happy for anyone to chip in with a better solution if they have one - especially one which does not include customising the PrimeFaces library...